# How to read data using ReadFile when file has disabled sharing on read

Tags: windows, security, winapi, readfile, file-sharing

I have a problem, i have a file who opened other process and this process defined in `CreateFile` non file sharing, then i have other application and i want read data from this
file in same time, but how to do.

I can't change file sharing in first application.
I can reach computer administrator right's, i can do changes in system, but probably "code" solution will be better for this problem if this can be done by code.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using [EasyHook](http://easyhook.codeplex.com) and hook in the API to the [CreateFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858%28VS.85%29.aspx) routine, in effect, your code will intercept the API and possibly change the `dwShareMode` parameter to make it FILE_SHARE_READ bitwise or FILE_SHARE_WRITE i.e. (FILE_SHARE_READ|FILE_SHARE_WRITE) and call the original hook to allow the CreateFile to work normally...

Comment: but i can hook only my application not target, this is good way but if i would be can do DLL injection on all applications working on system then i will hook CreateFile is good method.

Answer (score 1):

Use the backup API if you have sufficient privilege. Otherwise, note that these flags exist for a reason. If someone disabled sharing, it's disabled.

You want to call `BackupRead`, and MSDN notes the following:

> a backup
>   application must have access to the
>   system-level access control settings,
>   the ACCESS_SYSTEM_SECURITY flag must
>   be specified in the dwDesiredAccess
>   parameter value passed to CreateFile.value passed to CreateFile.

parameter value passed to CreateFile.

Comment: In some libraries when you open the file, sharing is disabled under the hood and the programmer doesn't even know if shareing is enabled or disabled. So your comment about "for a reason" isn ot applicable.

Comment: @Eug well, ok, there's only so much I can recommend to people stuck with the output of idiots. (e.g. libraries that forbid sharing for no good reason).

Answer (score 1):

One of the options is to use our [RawDisk](http://www.eldos.com/rawdisk/) product, which lets you bypass system security restrictions and open files, which have been opened exclusively or the ones for which you don't have access rights. Note, that installing RawDisk itself requires admin rights, so RawDisk can't be used for intrusion to other's computer.

Another option is to use backup API, i.e. above mentioned BackupRead() Windows API function. Doing [google search for BackupAPI](http://www.google.com/search?q=BackupRead) will give you not just description of this function, but also several comments from users about what's involved in using this backup API